# Why copy package.json and install dependencies before copying the rest of the project within docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've seen a lot of tutorials about how to build an application using docker and most of the time the Dockerfile copies package.json, package-lock.json then runs install, and finally copies the rest of the application.

**Example of Dockerfile copying package.json, package-lock.json before the rest of the application**

[Source](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-the-official-nginx-docker-image/)

```
FROM node:12.18.2 as build

ARG REACT_APP_SERVICES_HOST=/services/m

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json /app/package.json
COPY ./package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json

RUN yarn install
COPY . .
RUN yarn build


FROM nginx
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

It got me triggered why this approach and not copying the entire application and then running the install. If the intention is to not copy the node_modules folder, just adding the folder at the .dockerignore file would resolve this issue. Or it is another problem that it's been prevented when doing in this order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's done because of Docker layer caching. If you run `docker build` when none of the copied files have changed, the image layers will just be read from the cache. If a `COPY` file has changed, all layers *after* that in the image will be rebuilt.

`RUN yarn install` is an expensive operation and we don't want to need to execute it again when any random source files in the project change. This way, it's only re-executed if the `package.json` or `package-lock.json` files have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Docker images consist of layers. We can see layers, for example, when we pull an image. If we pull an image, we may see a message like "*layer already exists*", indicating that we have already downloaded this layer and do not need to re-download it again.

When we build an image from a containerfile, the instructions `RUN`, `COPY` and `ADD` in the containerfile create a new layer. Our goal is to layer our image in such a way that - read from top to bottom - the content changes less frequent.

Within our application, the most likely part to change is the source code itself. The dependencies of an app change less frequently. Hence, we want to layer the dependencies in a separate layer such that when we rebuild the container and only the source code changes, only the changes in source code can be pushed (and consequently pulled when we deploy), speeding up our deployment time.